# UIImageView change Background Color and setImage not working during Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

As the title said, it's very strange, did you agree?

So , if someone found your codes

```
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

or

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageName:@"angryBird"];"
```

are not working. Just mind that if your imageView is animating , or whether the animation has been removed or not.

－－－－－－－－－－**The Answer Below**－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

Just stop animating before you set image and change background of the animating UIImageView.

```
UIImageView* imageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];
//......do sth. like setFrame ...
imageView.images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects....]; // set the animation images array 
imageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
[imageView startAnimating];
//......do sth.
[imageView stopAnimating];        // **** do not forget this!!!!! ****
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageName:@"angryBird"];
```

When you performSelector: withObject: afterDey:1.0s , in the selector method , also, you need to **stopAnimating** too, and then setImage or change background color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change background color and changing the image once animation is complete. it will simply work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:: in this way

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(animationDidFinish:) withObject:nil
         afterDelay:instructions.animationDuration];
```

or use dispatch_after:

```
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, instructions.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         [self animationDidFinish];
    });
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: Before assigning image name as angryBird please double check your spell

Comment: thanks. It's not the frame's problem . I change imageView's background color before its animation stop, and the rigth way is that I should change the background color after its animation stop . Or, another way , stop its animation and then , change its background color.

Comment: so what u really want. Do u want to change background color after animation stop or before animation stop ?

Comment: yes : ) , its animation must stop , and change background color would work.

Comment: His thought is right. and , what i really want is to point out that : if someone want to change the UIImageView background color or image , he should stop its animating. put the code "[imageView stopAnimating]" before "imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]" . if not , set BGColor would failed. Many thanks @chandan, :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Animation using block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"]];
        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];


    }];
```

Note: It is `imageNamed:` not `imageName:` ,I am not sure how this get compiled

Comment: ;) , sorry ,forget about the "imageName:" and "angry bird", I wat not coding it in XCode.  i just write it in this textArea.